# I skipped Permission Requested Interface at the time of login with Azure . Provided 'Grant admin consent' permission. But MFA now disable

Tags: php, azure, drupal, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I skipped Permission Requested Interface at the time of login with Azure . Provide 'Grant admin consent' permission. But Azure OTP validation (Azure Multi-Factor Authentication) now disable.

SKipped Below Interface :

[image]

I want to Enable OTP validation(Azure Multi-Factor Authentication) with 'Grant admin consent'. Please guide me.

I am using below code

```
$auth_url =  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize" 
$client_id =  "<client_id>"; 
$redirect_uri = "<redirect_uri>"; 
$data = array(
'response_type' => 'code',
'client_id' => $client_id,
'scope' => 'User.Read',
'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
'response_mode' => 'query',
);              
$auth_redirect_url = $auth_url.'?'.http_build_query($data);
drupal_goto($auth_redirect_url); exit;
```

MY Azure Back End permission image below :

[image]

> I Want to enable **OTP validation form**(Azure Multi-Factor Authentication) of Azure with '**Grant admin
>   consent**'

Comment: I don't think "Grant admin consent" will cause MFA to be disabled. If you have a conditional access policy which configures MFA for your app, it will not be modified by the "Grant admin consent" operation. Please try to clean the cookie of your browser or use an incognito window to have a retry.

Comment: @Allen Could you please guide me , how to configures MFA for my apps

Comment: Have you referred to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/app-based-mfa?

Comment: @AllenWu Thank you.. I will configure it. Let you know after completed it

Comment: @AllenWu We enable MFA , still MFA  validation form or OTP validation form is not appearing .. So now what I have to do , please Guide me

Comment: What form are you referring to? Can you post a screenshot? If the users have MFA enforced then they should be requested to enter a second form of identification.

Comment: In Scope parameter  I have to send resource . After that it worked..
like 'scope' => $client_id.'/.default', Here $client_id = 'APP ID'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this seems related to a conditional access policy or other setting that might be blocking MFA.

1. Ensure that you have disabled the setting for "Remember Multi-Factor Authentication." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-mfasettings#remember-multi-factor-authentication
2. Go to Azure Active Directory > Security > Conditional Access. You can ensure that there is no policy allowing MFA to be skipped, and if you want to be on the safe side you can create a new conditional access policy requiring MFA for all users. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/app-based-mfa

   **NOTE:** See, [Require MFA for All Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-all-users-mfa)
3. Go to aka.ms/mfasetup and make sure that MFA is set to "Enforced" for the individual users for whom you wish to enforce MFA. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates

Comment: In Scope parameter  I have to send resource . After that it worked..
like 'scope' => $client_id.'/.default', Here $client_id = 'APP ID'